# download links not showing up Order history Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob

I am trying to display my download links on the page that displays all your purchases.  This code below just does not seem to work.

```
<h1>Your Purchases</h1>
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders" author_id="CURRENT_USER" status="open|Completed|closed|Registration Closed"}
{exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}" variable_prefix="items_"}
{if items_first_item}
Total number of items: {items_total_results}.
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td width="60">ID</td>
<td width="350">Title</td>
<td width="20">Qty</td>
<td width="90">Invoice</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{/if}
<tr class="{items_switch="odd|even"}">
                        <td valign="top">#{items_count}: {items_entry_id}</td>
                        <td valign="top">
                      {items_title}{if items_size} - {items_size}{/if}</td>
                      <td valign="top">{items_quantity}</td>
                      <td valign="top"><a href="{path=courses/invoice}/{entry_id}">View invoice</a></td>
<td valign="top">     
{if item:product_download_url}
<span ><a href="{exp:cartthrob:get_download_link field='product_download_url' entry_id='{item:entry_id}'}">Download</a></span>
{/if}
    {if purchased_license_number}
    <p>License number: {purchased_license_number}</p>
    {/if}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {if items_count == items_total_results}
                </tbody>
        </table>
        {/if}
    {/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
    {if no_results}
<p><strong>You have no orders in your account.</strong></p>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had success using the following to display download links:

```
{exp:cartthrob:download_file_form field="product_download_url" entry_id="{item:entry_id}" }
        <input type="submit" value="Download Now!" /> 
{/exp:cartthrob:download_file_form}
```

Also, I don't know if it would make a difference but what happens if instead of

`order_id="{entry_id}"`

you use

`order_id="{purchased_order_id}"`